# C# Huge memory leak when scrolling using OwnerDraw/DrawItem in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I've recently started profiling my WinForms application and notice a huge memory leak when scrolling up and down my ListView.

This leak does not happen if I don't do my own custom rendering via .OwnerDraw and DrawItem.

My ListView consists of an image, text and a rectangle which is drawn on top of selected objects. Am I missing some cleanup? It seems like it's redrawing stuff endlessly, which is why the memory usage is stacking up.

It climbs to over 100mb of memory usage within 10 seconds if I continuously scroll up and down the list. The memory usage stays consistent if I don't use OwnerDraw.

According to examples i've seen though, my usage seems valid.

Thanks for any assistance.

```cs
// ## Inside form load ## //
listView2.OwnerDraw = true;
listView2.DrawItem += new DrawListViewItemEventHandler(listView2_DrawItem);

// ## How the items are added to the ListView (in form load) ## //

// Create an image list
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
imageList.ImageSize = new Size(256, 178);
imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
// Assign the image list to the listView
listView2.LargeImageList = imageList;
// Create an array of 20 listView items
ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[20];

// Create 20 items
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    // Add the image for this item to the image list
    imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("myFile2.jpg"));
    // Create the item
    items[i] = new ListViewItem("Item");
    items[i].ImageIndex = i;
    // Add the item to the listView
    listView2.Items.Add(icons[i]);
}

// ## Draw item handler ## //
private void listView2_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{   
    Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 10, e.Bounds.Top + 10, 256, 178);
    Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(rect3.Left, e.Bounds.Top, rect3.Width, e.Bounds.Height + 14);
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
            TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;

    // Draw the image for this item
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Item.ImageList.Images[e.ItemIndex], rect3);

    // Draw the text and the surrounding rectangle.
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, new Font("Arial", 12), rect4, Color.Black, flags);

    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        int width = e.Item.ImageList.Images[e.ItemIndex].Width;
        int height = e.Item.ImageList.Images[e.ItemIndex].Height;
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(180, 1, 1, 1));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect3);

        TextFormatFlags flags2 = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;

        // Draw the text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, new Font("Arial", 12), rect3, Color.White, flags2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you are actually leaking memory (besides the Font and the Brush)? GC only sets in when needed; so memory usage often piles up until then..

Comment: I'm going off task manager at the moment. It can use 100mb of memory in under 10 seconds if I scroll up and down constantly. I believe it's leaking as it does not happen when the default drawing is used, only when I control the drawing. I haven't tried to keep going past 100+ MB yet to see if it caps out. I'm concerned due to the standard form draw not leaking at all (mem usage didn't climb with the default draw)

Comment: Sounds quite normal. 100MB is nothing in a machine with GB RAM and no contending programs. Add the missing using clauses and try to bring it really up to a larger 'leak'..!

Comment: The 100mb happens even with just the draw call to the image list item being the only code there. I know the usage didn't seem that high in context, but why does it not climb when using the default drawing code (not using owner draw), but does with? That's what isn't adding up for me

Comment: @TaW Turns out that you were right. It keeps climbing up until roughly ~1GB then the garbage collector kicks in. Guess it's normal after all. I'm new to C# and its memory management, so I just assumed it was leaking initially. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
this.listView2.LargeImageList.Draw(e.Graphics, gameItemRect.Left, gameItemRect.Top, gameItemRect.Width, gameItemRect.Height, e.ItemIndex);
```

This uses the internal handle instead of creating a copy of the image.
Also the brush and font needed pre-initializing outside of the code block, to prevent recreating them for every draw event and leaking memory, as stated by @Tim. The main memory leak was due to the image draw call however.

Now memory usage is consistent with that of not using OwnerDraw.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dispose both of your new Font("Arial", 12) objects and your Brush.

You are leaking more than memory, you are also leaking GDI objects.

You can either create the font once when your form loads and dispose it when it closes (better performance), or create and dispose of it with a using block in the DrawItem block that needs it (slower, but simpler code)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Problem is, the main leak is in the call to draw the image list item. If everything else is commented out, aside from that and the rect3 object, I can leak 100mb of memory by scrolling up and down continuously in about 10 seconds